# How to change a button name through an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uibutton

How do I fetch the value from API to an array and put that value into a button as its title from starting index.

For example, button 1 is named by array, index 0; button 2 is named by index 1 and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[urButton setTitle:[urArray objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```